# code does not produce an error but runs and i know its not right

Tags: python

What i am trying to do is write my first program on my own. i don't want the answer but just some guidance its been two days and i haven't made any real progress. I'm a newbie so go easy on me.

Four co-workers carpool to work each day. A driver is selected randomly for the drive to work and again randomly for the drive home. Each of the drivers has a lead foot, and each has a chance of being ticketed for speeding. Driver A has a 10 percent chance of getting a ticket each time he drives, Driver B a 15 percent chance, Driver C a 20 percent chance, and Driver D a 25 percent chance. The state will immediately revoke the license of a driver after his or her third ticket, and a driver will stop driving in the carpool once his license is revoked. Since there is only one police officer on the carpool route, a maximum of one ticket will be issued per morning and a max of one per evening

```
import random

day_counter = 0
alan_tickets = 0
betty_tickets = 0
charles_tickets = 0
diana_tickets = 0

drivers = ["Alan", "Betty", "Charles", "Diana"]

#def head_to_work(): is the driver selection process when heading to work.
def head_to_work():
    if random.choice(drivers) == "Alan":
        print "Alan it's your turn."
        global alan_tickets
        if alan_tickets == 3:
            print "i cant"
            head_to_work()
        else:
            return alan_drives_tw()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Betty":
        print "Betty it's your turn."
        global betty_tickets
        if betty_tickets == 3:
            print "nope"
            head_to_work()
        else:
            return betty_drives_tw()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Charles":
        print "Charles it's your turn."
        global charles_tickets
        if charles_tickets == 3:
            print "no way"
            head_to_work()
        else:
            return charles_drives_tw()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Diana":
        print "Diana it's your turn."
        global diana_tickets
        if diana_tickets == 3:
            print "sorry guys"
            head_to_work()
        else:
            return diana_drives_tw()
    else:
        print "All drivers have their Licenses suspended."
        print "Take the Bus."

# driver alan is heading to work he has a 10% chance of getting a ticket
def alan_drives_tw():
    global alan_tickets
    print "Yo i'm driving"
    print "..."
    print "Now driving"
    print "..."
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random <= 0.10:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        alan_tickets += 1
        print "i got a ticket, but we have arrived at work"
        head_home()
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "we have arrived at work"
        head_home()

# driver betty is heading to work she has a 15% chance of getting a ticket
def betty_drives_tw():
    global betty_tickets
    print "Hi i'll drive"
    print "..."
    print "we outta here"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.15:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        betty_tickets += 1
        print "i got a ticket but, made it to work"
        head_home()
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "made it to work"
        head_home()

#driver charles is heading to work he has a 20% chance of getting a ticket
def charles_drives_tw():
    global charles_tickets
    print "I'll take the wheel"
    print "..."
    print "lets roll out"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.20:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        charles_tickets += 1
        print "i got a ticket but, made it to work"
        head_home()
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "made it to work"
        head_home()

#driver charles is heading to work she has a 25% chance of getting a ticket
def diana_drives_tw():
    global diana_tickets
    print "I got it today"
    print "..."
    print "whippin it"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.25:
        print "its ticket time"
        diana_tickets += 1
        print "i got a ticket but, were here at work"
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "were here at work"
        return head_home()


#def head_home(): is the driver selection process when heading home
def head_home():
    if random.choice(drivers) == "Alan":
        print "Alan it's your turn"
        global alan_tickets
        if alan_tickets == 3:
            print "i cant"
            return head_home()
        else:
            return alan_drives_h()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Betty":
        print "Betty it's your turn"
        global betty_tickets
        if betty_tickets == 3:
            print "nope"
            return head_home()
        else:
            return betty_drives_h()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Charles":
        print "Charles it's your turn"
        global charles_tickets
        if charles_tickets == 3:
            print "no way"
            return head_home()
        else:
            return charles_drives_h()
    elif random.choice(drivers) == "Diana":
        print "Diana it's your turn"
        global diana_tickets
        if diana_tickets == 3:
            print "sorry guys"
            return head_home()
        else:
            return diana_drives_h()
    else:
        print "Drivers are not eligible to drive"

# driver alan is heading to work he has a 10% chance of getting a ticket
def alan_drives_h():
    global alan_tickets
    global day_counter
    print "Yo i'm driving"
    print "..."
    print "Now driving"

    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random <= 0.10:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        alan_tickets += 1
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "were home"
        day_counter += 1
        head_to_work()

# driver betty is heading to work she has a 15% chance of getting a ticket
def betty_drives_h():
    global betty_tickets
    global day_counter
    print "Hi i'll drive"
    print "..."
    print "we outta here"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.15:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        betty_tickets += 1
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "made it home"
        day_counter += 1
        head_to_work()

# driver charles is heading to work he has a 20% chance of getting a ticket
def charles_drives_h():
    global charles_tickets
    global day_counter
    print "I'll take the wheel"
    print "..."
    print "lets roll out"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.20:
        print "your getting a ticket"
        charles_tickets += 1
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "made it home guys"
        day_counter += 1
        head_to_work()

# driver diana is heading to work she has a 25% chance of getting a ticket
def diana_drives_h():
    global diana_tickets
    global day_counter
    print "I got it today"
    print "..."
    print "whippin it"
    print "your getting pulled over"
    if random.random() <= 0.25:
        print "its ticket time"
    else:
        print "just a warning today"
        print "were home everyone"
        day_counter += 1
        head_to_work()

print head_to_work()
print "Alan %d tikets." % (alan_tickets)
print "Betty %d tickets." % (betty_tickets)
print "Charles %d tickets." % (charles_tickets)
print "Diana %d tickets." % (diana_tickets)
print "%d days has passed." % (day_counter)
```

there are several problems that i come across.

1. get the code to keep running till everyone has 3 tickets
2. sometimes it stops after 1,2,3, or 4 days max and i have no idea why

thanks in advance remember no answers just clues and guidance

Comment: You really should use lists instead of separate variables and functions for each driver, so you don't have so much repeated code.

Comment: This would actually be a good application for a `class driver` where you hold the probability of getting a ticket and the number of tickets the driver has gotten.

Comment: When you call `head_to_work()` recursively you're not returning the value, it should be `return head_to_work()`. Or use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: None of the `xxx_drives_tw()` or `xxx_drives_h()` functions return anything.

Comment: All that repetition makes the code harder to understand and harder to debug. Please see [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: awesome thank you i was thinking i should add some classes but didn't know where to start. but ill definitely try that. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting a random item from a list, and comparing it to multiple values, you should only make a random selection once.

```
if random.choice(drivers) == "Alan":
    ...
elif random.choice(drivers) == "Betty":
```

This selects a random driver and compares it to 'Alan'.  If it IS Alan, the if block runs correctly.  If it fails, it now calls the `random.choice` function again, and selects a NEW random driver to compare to 'Betty'.  But, that random driver could be Alan (or anyone).

You want something more like this:

```
driver = random.choice(drivers)
if driver == 'Alan':
    ...
elif driver == 'Betty':
    ...
```

Some other quick thoughts:

Print statements are a good way to debug a program - but that's virtually impossible with as much print spam as you have.  Comment most of that out until the program works - and add print statements to show you what variables are at different times.

You have several typos such as `random.random` instead of `random.random()` and functions where you forget to update counters.  This is due primarily to having so many *very* similar functions.  As you keep writing programs, you're going to want to learn how to make a single function that can handle any of the four drivers for a single trip.  It will be easier to program, and reduce some of the typo errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental flaw in your code. In your `head_to_work` function `random.choice(drivers)` is present in each of `if` `elif` clause that is where unpredictability lies. You should improve upon by like this.

```
drivers = ["Alan", "Betty", "Charles", "Diana"]
available_drivers=drivers[:]
def head_to_work():
    if available_drivers:
        selected_driver=random.choice(available_drivers)
    else:
        selected_driver= None
    if selected_driver == "Alan":
        print "Alan it's your turn."
        global alan_tickets
        if alan_tickets == 3:
            available_drivers.remove("Alan")
            print "i cant"
            head_to_work()
        else:
            return alan_drives_tw()
    #Similiarly for the other three.
    else:
        print "All drivers have their Licenses suspended."
        print "Take the Bus."
```

What we did here is removed the unnecessary random choices. Solved the unpredictability. Also maintaining a `avaliable_drivers` list helps in finding the non-ticketed drivers which is the essential condition for the `else` clause in `head_to_work` function to work.Since when all drivers get ticketed random.choice will get an empty list. And this will work until all the drivers will get ticketed.

Comment: when i do this i get an index out of range error. how do i get it to stop looking for drivers when all drivers have been removed from the list?

Comment: @Louis_Louisius Change it accordingly described above.